# Issues on Load String Array randomly by using loop and add into datagridview

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, random, datagridview

I am a VB.NET beginner. I had faced the issues on loading string array randomly and add into datagridview.

For the project, first of all, I will import the data from excel to datagridview. After that, I need to load the string array randomly and put it into the new column (ColumnC) added into datagridview. I have 4 string values, and I want the loop to be able to load 1 to 4 string values(minimum 1 to maximum 4) randomly into the column of datagridview.

For example:

```
Array = {"abc", "cde", "efg","hij"}
```

For the output, I want a random number of these 4 string values able to load into the columnC of datagridview, which mean that the output should be:

```
-----------------------------------------------
ColumnA || ColumnB || ColumnC         ||
----------------------------------------
1       ||3        ||**abc, cde**         ||
----------------------------------------
2       ||5        ||**abc**              ||
----------------------------------------
3       ||7        ||**abc, cde, efg,hij**||
----------------------------------------
4       ||9        ||**cde, efg**         ||
----------------------------------------
```

My code so far:

```
Dim rnd As New Random()
    Dim ARR As String() = {"abc", "cde", "efg", "hij"}
    For Each value In ARR.OrderBy(Function(x) Rnd.Next())
        DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(1).Value = value
    Next
```

After loading the string loop randomly, I would like to add the random value into each row of ColumnC too. From the code, I am only able to load one random string value into 1 row of ColumnC only.

How can I solve my issue?

Comment: Use a `For` loop rather than `For Each`. Then you can use the loop counter as an index into more than one list. Call `ToArray` after `OrderBy` to get an array that you can index and you can obviously index the `Rows` collection.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is always replacing the first row and first column:

```
DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(1).Value = value
```

If you add a counter this will do the trick:

```
Dim rnd As New Random()
Dim rowcounter As Int
Dim ARR As String() = {"abc", "cde", "efg", "hij"}
For Each value In ARR.OrderBy(Function(x) Rnd.Next())
    DataGridView1.Rows(rowcounter).Cells(1).Value = value
    rowcounter = rowcounter + 1
Next
```

UPDATE

```
    Dim rnd As New Random()
    Dim ARR As String() = {"abc", "cde", "efg", "hij"}
    Dim nbvalues As Integer
    Dim colvalue As String

    'Fill 4 rows
    For i = 1 To 4
        nbvalues = rnd.Next(ARR.Length - 1) + 1  ' avoid 0 values
        colvalue = ""

        For j = 1 To nbvalues
            If colvalue = "" Then
                colvalue = ARR(rnd.Next(ARR.Length))
            Else
                colvalue = colvalue & "," & ARR(rnd.Next(ARR.Length - 1) + 1)
            End If
        Next

        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = colvalue
        'Console.WriteLine("Rows(" & i & ") ) " & colvalue)
    Next
```

Comment: Hi @SuperPoney, thank you for your solution. I still have an issue. I would like to load the ColumnC randomly by giving each of the columns having at least min 1 to max 4 string values by using random looping? This means the result might be row1 of columnC has 3 values, row 2 has 2 values, row 3 have 1 value, while row 4 have all of 4 values. May I know what is your opinion for the solution to solve it?

Comment: You need to use `Rnd` inside the `For` and compose you value based on this random value. I'll update my answer. BTW @jmcilhinney advice is right.

Comment: @aliceteh Did you manage to solve your problem? Please advice.

Comment: Dear @SuperPoney, sorry for the late reply. I had solved my problem. Thank you for the solution!